# Unsticking game objects

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I have used

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    collision.gameObject.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
}
```

To stick two players together when they connect.

Basically after they have collided the second game object is still stuck to the original object and i need that not to be the case.

How do i make the game object not stuck when they come apart ?

Comment: So are asking how to dissolve the parent-child relationship between two game objects?

Comment: Under what specific conditions or event do you want to unstick the objects? Here it looks like they attach on contact. What should cause them to detach?

Comment: yes but ive got it now thanks

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post your solution as an Answer, so this question isn't left as a dead end for future users searching the site for help.